# How to find files with given extension in particular level of sub directory with specified pattern using python?

Tags: python

In bash it can be easily done using grep like this:

`grep "$pattern" $directory/*/*/*/level4/*.txt* > out/$pattern.txt`

where `$pattern` is the pattern, `$directory` is the base directory and we are looking for .txt files only at the 4th level subdirectories with the name `level4`. And possibly redirecting the output to file with the pattern name itself. This works perfectly in bash. Is there an easy equivalent in Python?

I tried iterating over all the subdirectories in `$directory` using `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk`, `endswith` & `find` but that would look at all files instead of the 4th level with specified name.

Comment: Have you looked at [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html)?

Comment: Thanks @AnoopRDesai. glob looks promising. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import glob
import re

pattern = 'directory_name/*/*/*/level4/*.txt*'
regex = re.compile(r'.*test.*')

for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
    with open(filename) as file_desc:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(file_desc):
            if not regex.match(line):
                continue
            output = '{}:{} {}'.format(filename, line_num, line)
            print(output, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be equivalent to your bash command (but I didn't test it). I wanted to give an answer that shouldn't require tweaking and uses pathlib (which is amazing).

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

directory = Path('mydir')
out_directory = Path('out')

pattern = 'my (neat|cool|sick) pattern'
out_file = out_directory / f'{pattern}.txt'

with out_file.open('w') as out:
    # this type of pattern is a `glob`
    for found_file in directory.glob('*/*/*/level4/*.txt*')
        with found_file.open('r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if re.search(pattern, line):
                    print(line, file=out)
```